# usage of HAS in tenses

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, perfect-aspect

"she RETURNED 2 days ago
and
she HAS KNOWN me for 2 yrs"

Why in the 2nd sentences we have used "HAS" and not in 1st sentence?

Comment: Most composition teachers would frown upon such temporal mixing, but it isn't ungrammatical here. The returning and the knowing simply occur over [different points in time](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846). Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many good references online describing when to use the simple past ("returned") and when to use the present perfect ("has known"). Briefly, the simple past is used to describe a past event at a particular time, which might be a moment, a day, a year, a century, and so forth. In contrast, the present perfect describes a past event from the viewpoint of the present where often the result of the past event is of most importance.

Answer (score -1):

The verb 'to know' is different from the verb 'to return' in the sense once you know somebody you know them for ever. Some one can return many times. The tenses used in the example seem natural to me. Returned two days ago -past tense referring to fixed time in the past. She has known me for two years - Present perfect She met you two years ago and has known you ever since.

Comment: The second half of this answer is precisely right. Sadly, the first half is nonsense. Once you know somebody, you do not know them forever. (For starters, you don't *live* forever. And then there's that thing called *forgetting*.) You can totally say "she knew me for two years", and you can totally say "she has returned". Both verbs can, and do, occur in either tense. The tenses just mean different things. Which is the whole point of having them in the first place.